# select N items for every group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables:

```
Category:  Id, Name...
News:   Id, Title

News_Category_Mapping:  Id, NewsId, CategoryId
```

Where newsid, categoryid are foreign keys to these 2 tables.

News_category_mapping:

```
Id  NewsID CategoryId
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     3        1
4     4        3 
5     5        5
6     6        3
```

so i may want to get maximum 2 news items from every categoryid, say like

```
Id  NewsID CategoryId
1     1        1
2     2        1
4     5        3
6     6        3
5     5        5
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: any 2? or ordered by some crtieria? what version of SQL Server? If it's 2008, use the `RANK()` function.

Comment: care to give more information on the tables, i.e. all the columns and their data types, something like a desired output and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT C.Id,N.Id,N.Title,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NC.CategoryID ORDER BY NC.NewsId)
 FROM News_Category_Mapping NC JOIN
     News N ON NC.NewsId=N.Id JOIN
     Category C ON NC.CategoryId=C.Id)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN<3
```

**Explanation:**

Here, the inner query selects the records along a row number RN. To know how the query works, please execute the inner query first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169550/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-cte-subquery-and-temp-tables

Answer (score 1):

Let say you need 2 items each

```
Select *
From Category C
    CROSS APPLY (Select top 2  Id,CatId,NewsName  
                 From News Nw where Nw.CatId=C.Id) As N
```

Here is the [fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33db5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY, like so:

```
Select c.*, Sub.*
from
  Categories c cross apply
  (
    select top 2 
      * 
    from 
      News n 
    where 
    exists
    (
       select 1 
       from NewsCategories nc 
       where nc.CatId = c.id and n.id = nc.NewsId
    )
  ) Sub
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31b5d/6) for this

Comment: Sorry, copied the link before it finished executing, its fixed now, thanks for the heads up.