# How to prevent CTE execution until reached OR NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have an SQL Server query that uses some [CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It has two tables that it selects the data from. The two tables are identical in structure, but not necessary data. The query will first select from `table_a` and if no rows are fetched, it then selects from `table_b`. The query is something like this:

```sql
;WITH cte_a AS (
  ...
), cte_b AS (
  ...
) 
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a
OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table_b
  INNER JOIN cte_b ON condition_b
)
```

The current problem that I have is that `cte_b` will always be executed regardless of whether `table_a` returns any rows. This is not very ideal for me; I would like to have `cte_b` **execute if and only if** the subquery for `table_a` returns no rows.

I tried moving the `cte_b` to be just before the subquery for `table_b` as

```sql
;WITH cte_a AS (
  ...
)
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a
OR NOT EXISTS (
  ;WITH cte_b AS (
    ...
  ) 
  SELECT *
  FROM table_b
  INNER JOIN cte_b ON condition_b
)
```

However, the IDE complains. I think that this wasn't the way CTEs are supposed to be used.

Comment: You will need to use an SP and `IF` conditions. There is no way to **reliably** force query optimiser to execute (or not execute) parts of queries conditionally.

Comment: What's more CTEs may even be executed multiple times, when they are referenced more than once. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/706983/6305294 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169550/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-cte-sub-query-temporary-table-or-ta

Comment: @Alex Using `IF` conditions will mean that CTEs will not be used right?

Comment: Something along the lines of @gotqn answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create temporary table for storing the data - split the query to two separate `INSERT` statements, where the second is executed only in no data is populated after first query is completed. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEmp
(

);


;WITH cte_a AS (
  ...
)
INSERT INTO #TEmp
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TEmp)
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO #TEmp
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM table_b
  INNER JOIN cte_b ON condition_b
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of CTE's.

The best thing would be to not use a CTE and use a join, but I assume you can't.

I'd suggest you try using a sub-query so the engine can process it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using a union, and then excluding the second half of the union on `cte_b` should the first CTE have any results.

```
;WITH cte_a AS (
    ...
),
cte_b AS (
    ...
)

SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN cte_b ON condition_b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_a
    INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a
)
```

Comment: `cte_b` is still executed in all cases, right? I want to execute `cte_b`, which can take a long time, only if there is no records from `table_a` subquery.

Comment: @krismath No, the `WHERE` clause containing the not exists clause would be executed _first_, and the second CTE would only run should the A CTE be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH    cte1 AS
        (
        ....
        ),
        cte2 AS
        (
        ...
        )

SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN cte_a ON condition_a ---Choose Your Condition...

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table_b
INNER JOIN cte_b ON condition_b ---Choose Your Condtion....
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte2)
```

**Note:-**

A `CTE` must be followed by a single `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE` statement that references some or all the `CTE columns`.