# Making sure only 1 record if multiple data is returned in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been hacking at this for a while, but cannot seem to get it to work.  I think some other SQL Server function or criteria that might be beyond me is needed to get it to work.

I have this sample data set:

```
Test1@gmail.com FirstName LastName
Test1@gmail.com DiffFirstName DiffLastName
MyOtherEmail@gmail.com Jane Doe
MyOtherEmail@gmail.com John Doe
MyOtherEmail@gmail.com Jack Doe
```

What I need is that data returned where we only take the first row is the email is duplicated and the other is discarded as we do not need it.  So, this would be the selected return set:

```
Test1@gmail.com FirstName LastName
MyOtherEmail@gmail.com Jane Doe
```

I was trying group by, Over, Partition By, and Temp Tables, but I just could not seem to get around having all the names returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Dennis

Comment: Try `TOP 1` to limit your result

Comment: What criteria would you use to sort the names to determine which is "first"?

Comment: Does the table have a unique primary key field that can be used?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. You don't even need to modify your table structure (although you still may want to).

```
SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName FROM (
    SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY LastName) AS RowNum
    FROM Table1
) a
WHERE a.RowNum = 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` inside the `PARTITION` will determine which record floats to the top. I used LastName to sort by. Change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ROW_NUMBER() with PARTITION BY and ORDER BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). Modify the ORDER BY clause to suit your needs.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2148a/15)

```
WITH contacts as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY first_name) AS row,
         email, first_name, last_name
  FROM contact
)
SELECT * FROM contacts where row = 1;
```

Similar to [Ellesedil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844080/366335) except using a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) instead of subquery. Note differences mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706972/difference-between-cte-and-subquery).

Answer (score 0):

Add an int ID to your table.
Make it the PK of your table.
Any table needs a PK anyway and you 
don't have a suitable column for PK.

Then do something like this.

```
select t1.* from
TableName t1
inner join 
(
    select t0.email, min(t0.id) as id 
    from TableName t0
    group by t0.email
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the DISTINCT keyword might be what you are looking for.

Comment: DISTINCT would deal with those three duplicated rows.But it would not resolve these two: Test1@gmail.com FirstName LastName
Test1@gmail.com DiffFirstName DiffLastName

Comment: Thanks Keith. I must be reading his question wrongly. I thought he wanted the distinct email addresses. I'd usually group them by that column and pull out the distinct addresses.