# Correct way to use database locking to randomly return single record not already in use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-locking

I have a table that acts somewhat of a queue except records are never removed from the table. What I am trying to attempt is have the stored procedure return a single record that is not currently being processed from a front end application. What we have is a "Locked" column we set to indicate this. The reason we are doing this is so only one call center agent can work on a record at a time. Here is what my sql looks like so far. The problem is if I run this query from two separate sessions (the second session comments out the waitfor statement) the second session does not return any records for 10 seconds. I've narrowed it down to the order by clause when selecting a record. If I remove the Order By it returns but I need the order by.

Or maybe my query is competently wrong? should I be using a transaction isolation level (serializable, snapshot)?? any guidance would be great!

```
DECLARE @WorkItemId INT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

/* TODO: Skip Records That Have Been Completed. */
SET @WorkItemId = (SELECT TOP 1 CampaignSetDetailId FROM CampaignSetDetail WITH (XLOCK, READPAST) WHERE LockedBy IS NULL ORDER BY NEWID(), NumAttempts ASC);

/* */
UPDATE CampaignSetDetail SET LockedBy = 'MPAUL', LockedDTM = GETUTCDATE() WHERE CampaignSetDetailId = @WorkItemId;

/* */
SELECT * FROM CampaignSetDetail WHERE CampaignSetDetailId = @WorkItemId;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: thank you i was in the middle of fixing the code block

Comment: generating a new guid for every row is an expensive way to randomize the order. Do you want a "random" not `Locked` or just the next or any row that is not `Locked`?

Comment: thats fine but even if i remove the new guid it still does not work with the order by clause in there.

Comment: I've decided I'm not sure what your asking. Do you want to read dirty data if some other transaction is updating the table? I doubt that is a good idea.

Comment: of course not. im confused on where you are confused :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - a set of retry attempts, and also using update lock.

```
  DECLARE @RetryCount Int = 1
  DECLARE @MaxRetries Int = 5;
  SET @RetryCount = 1 
  WHILE @RetryCount < @MaxRetries
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY

            /* TODO: Skip Records That Have Been Completed. */
         SET @WorkItemId = (
                            SELECT TOP 1
                                    CampaignSetDetailId
                            FROM    CampaignSetDetail WITH (UPDLOCK)
                            WHERE   LockedBy IS NULL
                            ORDER BY NEWID()
                                   ,NumAttempts ASC
                           );

         UPDATE   CampaignSetDetail WITH (UPDLOCK)
         SET      LockedBy = 'MPAUL'
                 ,LockedDTM = GETUTCDATE()
         WHERE    CampaignSetDetailId = @WorkItemId;

         SELECT   *
         FROM     CampaignSetDetail WITH (UPDLOCK)
         WHERE    CampaignSetDetailId = @WorkItemId;

         SELECT   @RetryCount = @MaxRetries;
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
         IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (1204, 1205, 1222)
            BEGIN
               SET @RetryCount += 1;
               WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
            END 
         ELSE
            THROW;
      END CATCH
   END
```

For more details about specific lock errors, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258769%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). This should work even if updates on the same table are executed from other sessions.

Comment: running some tests now. just out of curiosity would my example not work correctly if the table was updated from another session? because that will be happening once i add a 'completed' column

Comment: Using the table hint UPDLOCK - it should work even if updating from another session at the same time.

Comment: ok both answers seem to work but i'm not sure which one would be better for concurrency as many users will be hitting the proc at a time

Comment: You don't have a transaction around the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements so what will stop multiple collisions? Hoping collisions won't happen 5 times in a row seems somewhere between wasteful and risky to me. @Marco

Comment: That is in fact the idea behind it. Here we have an update, and also a select and we expect the rows, page or table to hold an update lock instead of a shared one. So when we have a select, the updates will not happen and we'll have a no. of retries to prevent locks here. This is the expected behavior. Had I not included the hint in my example, default transaction isolation would take place.

Comment: thank you both i'm going to run some more extensive tests and update the question in a little while.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one statement

```
DECLARE @WorkItemId INT;

UPDATE [CampaignSetDetail]
    SET
            [LockedBy] = 'MPAUL',
            [LockedDTM] = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE
            [CampaignSetDetailId] = (
                SELECT TOP 1
                            [CampaignSetDetailId],
                            @WorkItemId = [CampaignSetDetailId]
                    FROM
                            [CampaignSetDetail]
                    WHERE
                            [LockedBy] IS NULL
                    ORDER BY
                            [NumAttempts]);

SELECT
            * -- You shouldn't do this.
    FROM
            [CampaignSetDetail]
    WHERE
            [CampaignSetDetailId] = @WorkItemId;
```

I'm assuming `[CampaignSetDetailId]` forms the clustered index on the table. You could consider an index like,

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_CampaignSetDetail_NumAttempts]
    ON [CampaignSetDetail]([NumAttempts])
    WHERE [LockedBy] IS NULL;
```

to optimize this operation.

Comment: the wait was only in there for testing purposes

Comment: what about the return statement?

Comment: What `RETURN` statement?

Comment: i'm sorry i meant select to return the data. * was only for demonstration purposes. sry

Comment: is it possible with the above code that one session could set the lockedby at the same time as another session? i guess the question i am asking is would it be possible for two sessions to return the same record at the same time

Comment: @marco each statement runs within an implicit transaction. How data locks and integrity are maintained depend on the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` and any locking hints you might provide. To quote "The Database Engine query optimizer almost always chooses the correct locking level." This statement clearly contains an `UPDATE` so I expect the right choice to be made here unless you've changed the default isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189857(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a good solution but i am still evaluating all the answers. i am also trying to use a CTE and this is giving me the best performance right now.

```
DECLARE @WorkItemId INT;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 [CampaignSetDetailId], LockedBy FROM [dbo].[CampaignSetDetail] WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) WHERE LockedBy IS NULL ORDER BY NEWID(), NumAttempts ASC
)
UPDATE CTE SET LockedBy = 'DIESEL', @WorkItemId = [CampaignSetDetailId]

SELECT @WorkItemId

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
```

Comment: Surely, ordering by `NEWID()` then `[NumAttempts]` is a waste, ditch either but I'd suggest `NEWID()` as I don't think the "randomness" it provides is necessary.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the use of a CTE over a subquery either way. It have to compare the generated query plans and their performance but its entirely likely they could be identical. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706972/difference-between-cte-and-subquery