# Select all entries that match the oldest entry

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

In MariaDB / MySQL I have a table like this:

`table (key1, key2, date)` with `INDEX(key1, key2)`

Now I want to take the oldest entry:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1
```

And finally all entries matching `key1` and `key2` from the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `key1` = ? AND `key2` = ?
```

Can this be simplified into one query somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `join`:

```
select t.*
from `table` t join
     (select t.*
      from `table` t
      order by `date` asc
      limit 1
     ) tt
     on t.key1 = tt.key1 and t.key2 = tt.key2;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to write this query is available since MariaDB 10.2 introduced **Common Table Expressions**. Using the [WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/) syntax the query looks like this:

```
WITH t_oldest AS (SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` asc LIMIT 1)
SELECT t.* FROM `table` AS t,t_oldest 
WHERE t.key1 = t_oldest.key1 AND t.key2 = t_oldest.key2;
```

Comment: That looks interesting. Do you know if this query will have better/worse performance than the JOIN solution by Gordon Linoff?

Comment: No, I didn't carry out any performance tests but I would be interested if any such results were available.

I'd go along with Alex Pool's answer to a question on Stackoverflow which previously asked about differences between the two different approaches. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078464/difference-between-with-clause-and-subquery]

I personally find the WITH version more readable due to the use of a name (I used t_oldest in the above example). More complex queries will benefit even more in that aspect.