# PostgreSQL: SELECT count of rows that are not DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3, and I've got this big, ugly query...

```
SELECT cai.id
FROM common_activityinstance cai
JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-11'
    AND (   key = 'disable_student_nav' AND value = 'True'
         OR key = 'pacing' AND value = 'student');
```

...which gives me this result...

```
    id  
  ------
   1352
   1352
   1353
   1353
   1354
   1355
 (6 rows)
```

How can I improve my query to get the count of the duplicate rows (2 in this example)?

Comment: from the actual  select query ?

Comment: @wingedpanther: Good suggestion. That gives me the two duplicate IDs, but not the count. The number of rows that have two duplicate IDs could be in the thousands, so I don't want to return all that data from my server and have to count it on the client side.

Comment: Can an id appear more than twice?

Comment: From which of the tables do `key` and `value stem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *Sub-Query*

```
select count(*) total_dups from(
    SELECT count(cai.id)
    FROM common_activityinstance cai
    JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
    JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
    WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-11'
        AND (key = 'disable_student_nav'
                AND value = 'True'
                OR key = 'pacing'
                AND value = 'student')
    group by cai.id having count(cai.id) >1
    ) t
```

`group by cai.id having count(cai.id) > 1` can be used to find out duplicates count of each `cai.id`,Then `SELECT count(cai.id)(select ...)t` can be used to find out count of all duplicate in the *Sub-Query*.

*OR*

Using [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

```
with cte as (
SELECT count(cai.id)
    FROM common_activityinstance cai
    JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
    JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
    WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-11'
        AND (key = 'disable_student_nav'
                AND value = 'True'
                OR key = 'pacing'
                AND value = 'student')
    group by cai.id having count(cai.id) >1
    )

    select count(*) from  cte
```

[Difference between CTE and SubQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706976/3682599)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the structure of the query, I suspect that duplicates might only arise from the `or` part of the query.  If you are limited to at most two duplicates, you can do the calculation without a subquery:

```
SELECT count(cai.id) - count(distinct cai.id)
FROM common_activityinstance cai JOIN
     common_activityinstance_settings cais
     ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id JOIN
     common_activitysetting cas
     ON cas.id = cais.id
WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-11' AND
      (key, value) IN (('disable_student_nav', 'True'), ('pacing', 'student'));
```

Note:  This only works in the special case that each id appears only once or twice.