# SQL SERVER QUERY to select max value record per item

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

This is the sample table

[image]

What I need to achieve is to get or display only the record of tenant with the highest month value. If ever month is equal, I need to base on the latest date value. Here is the sample desired output

[image]

With this, I started by this code using max function and incorporated temp table, but unable to get the desired result.

```
select tenant, name,  date, month
into #sample
from tenant


select * 
from  #sample  
where months = (select max(months)from #sample)
```

and output to something like this. As I believe, the code is getting the max value in the whole list not considering per tenant filtering.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with the `row_number` window function:

```
select tenant, name, date, months
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by t.tenant, t.name order by t.months desc, t.date desc) as rn
          from TableName t) x
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: This worked. Can I just ask, does rn always return to 1?

Comment: For every distinct set of `tenant/name` (`partition by` clause), the `row_number` function will sequentially number the rows `1,2,3,4,...`, *always starting with `1`*, using the `order by` clause to determine the sequence.  So, because the `order by` clause is set to `t.months desc, t.date desc`, for every `tenant/name` combination, the row with the greatest `months` value (and latest `date` if more than one row has the same `months` value) will have an `rn` value of `1`.

Comment: To better understand this, try running the subquery on its own so that you can see the `rn` values for all the rows.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `row_number` function.

**Query**

```
;with cte as 
(
    select rn = row_number() over 
    (
        partition by tenant
        order by months desc,[date] desc
    ),*
    from table_name
)
select tenant,name,[date],months from cte
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of using the Common Table Expression over the subquery (as done in the other answer)?

Comment: A CTE can be used recursively; a sub-query cannot. This makes them especially well suited to tree structures.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706972/difference-between-cte-and-subquery

Comment: @Ajmot OK thanks, but just to be clear, there is no need for recursion in this particular application, right?

Comment: another difference CTE can be used several times as different table substitutes, sub-query can only be used once

Comment: @t-clausen.dk OK, I don't think we need that feature in this example either...that was my point.  I guess my question should have been more clear:  Is there any reason to use CTE over subquery **in this particular case**?

Comment: I don't see any improvement in using a CTE in this example in terms of logic or execution; however, IMO, CTEs make queries easier to read than inline views, so I generally prefer to use CTEs.