# Postgres' CTE vs Subquery Performance difference. Why?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression

I have two equivalent queries which extracts the average distance between buildings (table a) and the nearest highway (highways in table v) in a specific district (ace) and city (pro_com).

This is the CTE version

```
WITH subq AS (
SELECT a.n, a.geom as g1, unnest(ARRAY(SELECT v.geom as g2 
  FROM atlas_sezioni2 as v
  where v.code = '12230' and a.pro_com = v.pro_com and a.code <> v.code  
  ORDER BY a.geom <-> v.geom LIMIT 15)) as g2
FROM atlas_sezioni2 a
where a.pro_com = 15146 and a.ace = 1 and a.code IN('11100', '11210', '11220', '11230', '11240', '11300', '12100', '14200')  
)

select avg(dist) from (
select distinct on(n) n, dist
from (
SELECT n, ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2) as dist FROM subq
) disttable
order by n, dist asc
) final;
```

where in the CTE I extract the 15 nearest highways and calculate the distance, in order to use GIST indexes (http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html).
And the CTE's explain:

```
Aggregate  (cost=37342.10..37342.11 rows=1 width=8)
   CTE subq
     ->  Index Scan using atlas_sezioni2_code_ace_pro_com_n_idx on atlas_sezioni2 a  (cost=0.29..29987.90 rows=20900 width=236211)
       Index Cond: (((code)::text = ANY ('{11100,11210,11220,11230,11240,11300,12100,14200}'::text[])) AND (ace = 1) AND (pro_com = 15146::numeric))
       SubPlan 1
         ->  Limit  (cost=141.04..141.08 rows=15 width=236190)
               ->  Sort  (cost=141.04..141.21 rows=69 width=236190)
                     Sort Key: ((a.geom <-> v.geom))
                     ->  Index Scan using atlas_sezioni2_code_ace_pro_com_n_idx on atlas_sezioni2 v  (cost=0.28..139.35 rows=69 width=236190)
                           Index Cond: (((code)::text = '12230'::text) AND (a.pro_com = pro_com))
                           Filter: ((a.code)::text <> (code)::text)
   ->  Unique  (cost=7247.20..7351.70 rows=200 width=72)
     ->  Sort  (cost=7247.20..7299.45 rows=20900 width=72)
           Sort Key: subq.n, (_st_distance(geography(subq.g1), geography(subq.g2), 0::double precision, false))
           ->  CTE Scan on subq  (cost=0.00..5747.50 rows=20900 width=72)
(15 rows)
```

This is the equivalent with subqueries:

```
select avg(dist) from (
select distinct on(n) n, dist
from (
SELECT n, ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2) as dist FROM (
SELECT a.n, a.geom as g1, unnest(ARRAY(SELECT v.geom as g2 
  FROM atlas_sezioni2 as v
  where v.code = '12230' and a.pro_com = v.pro_com and a.code <> v.code  
  ORDER BY a.geom <-> v.geom LIMIT 15)) as g2
FROM atlas_sezioni2 a
where a.pro_com = 15146 and a.ace = 1 and a.code IN('11100', '11210', '11220', '11230', '11240', '11300', '12100', '14200')  
) subq
) disttable
order by n, dist asc
) final
```

and its explain

```
Aggregate  (cost=6366298.35..6366298.36 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Unique  (cost=6365932.60..6366037.10 rows=20900 width=236230)
     ->  Sort  (cost=6365932.60..6365984.85 rows=20900 width=236230)
           Sort Key: subq.n, (_st_distance(geography(subq.g1), geography(subq.g2), 0::double precision, false))
           ->  Subquery Scan on subq  (cost=0.29..35526.40 rows=20900 width=236230)
                 ->  Index Scan using atlas_sezioni2_code_ace_pro_com_n_idx on atlas_sezioni2 a  (cost=0.29..29987.90 rows=20900 width=236211)
                       Index Cond: (((code)::text = ANY ('{11100,11210,11220,11230,11240,11300,12100,14200}'::text[])) AND (ace = 1) AND (pro_com = 15146::numeric))
                       SubPlan 1
                         ->  Limit  (cost=141.04..141.08 rows=15 width=236190)
                               ->  Sort  (cost=141.04..141.21 rows=69 width=236190)
                                     Sort Key: ((a.geom <-> v.geom))
                                     ->  Index Scan using atlas_sezioni2_code_ace_pro_com_n_idx on atlas_sezioni2 v  (cost=0.28..139.35 rows=69 width=236190)
                                           Index Cond: (((code)::text = '12230'::text) AND (a.pro_com = pro_com))
                                           Filter: ((a.code)::text <> (code)::text)
(14 rows)
```

I know CTEs are boundary fences for optimization (Postgres doesn't optmize between CTEs and queries that are outside them), but this is strange. Why is the performance blowing out in this way?

Comment: I think you just answered that in the last para.

Comment: @CraigRinger mhh no... CTE has better performance even if it is not optmized :D

Comment: Well... if you run the query in the CTE term separately, how long does that take? What's the plan for that?

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Most complex queries I have perform *much* better when written as CTEs than as subqueries. It is a happy coincidence that CTEs are generally easier to read as well. But this has always boggled me a little for the exact reason you state: it *seems* they should be slower.

Comment: @CraigRinger isn't the thing you asked the first version I posted?

Comment: So ... are you saying that in this case the CTE-based form performs *better*, and that's what you're wondering about? You didn't include `ANALYZE`, timing information, etc. If the CTE form is faster than the subquery form, assuming an exact transformation between CTE and subquery, then the planner is making poor optimisation decisions in this case. `EXPLAIN (buffers, analyze)` detail might help.

Comment: @CraigRinger oops. True that. Analyze tells me the actual time is the same. Sorry. If you answer with this comment, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I still don't even understand what the question was. You've posted two plans (with no timing) and asked ... something?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I think the semicolon in `);` was not intended, the first query was supposed to be the CTE. BTW: omitting the CTE allows more freedom for the optimiser, including bad choices (i.e when statistics or tuning are absent/bad)

Answer (score 7):

As @CraigRinger said, I should have checked also the analyze. In fact, from "explain analyze" we see that the first one is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=58406.66..58406.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=138191.294..138191.295 rows=1 loops=1)
 CTE subq
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on atlas_sezioni2 a  (cost=9.93..51052.46 rows=20900 width=236211) (actual time=2.814..308.667 rows=3705 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (ace = 1)
         Filter: ((pro_com = 15146::numeric) AND ((code)::text = ANY ('{11100,11210,11220,11230,11240,11300,12100,14200}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4
         Heap Blocks: exact=42
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on atlas_sezioni2_ace_idx  (cost=0.00..9.88 rows=251 width=0) (actual time=0.110..0.110 rows=251 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (ace = 1)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Limit  (cost=240.70..240.74 rows=15 width=236190) (actual time=0.630..0.636 rows=15 loops=247)
                 ->  Sort  (cost=240.70..240.87 rows=69 width=236190) (actual time=0.627..0.630 rows=15 loops=247)
                       Sort Key: ((a.geom <-> v.geom))
                       Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on atlas_sezioni2 v  (cost=4.56..239.01 rows=69 width=236190) (actual time=0.045..0.518 rows=73 loops=247)
                             Recheck Cond: ((code)::text = '12230'::text)
                             Filter: (((a.code)::text <> (code)::text) AND (a.pro_com = pro_com))
                             Heap Blocks: exact=6916
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on atlas_sezioni2_code_idx  (cost=0.00..4.55 rows=73 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=73 loops=247)
                                   Index Cond: ((code)::text = '12230'::text)
 ->  Unique  (cost=7247.20..7351.70 rows=200 width=72) (actual time=138190.527..138191.243 rows=247 loops=1)
       ->  Sort  (cost=7247.20..7299.45 rows=20900 width=72) (actual time=138190.526..138190.800 rows=3705 loops=1)
             Sort Key: subq.n, (_st_distance(geography(subq.g1), geography(subq.g2), 0::double precision, false))
             Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 270kB
             ->  CTE Scan on subq  (cost=0.00..5747.50 rows=20900 width=72) (actual time=159.739..138182.891 rows=3705 loops=1)
 Planning time: 2.623 ms
 Execution time: 138217.574 ms
(27 rows)
```

while the subquery one is:

```
Aggregate  (cost=6387362.91..6387362.92 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=140208.005..140208.005 rows=1 loops=1)
 ->  Unique  (cost=6386997.16..6387101.66 rows=20900 width=236230) (actual time=140207.243..140207.947 rows=247 loops=1)
       ->  Sort  (cost=6386997.16..6387049.41 rows=20900 width=236230) (actual time=140207.241..140207.514 rows=3705 loops=1)
             Sort Key: subq.n, (_st_distance(geography(subq.g1), geography(subq.g2), 0::double precision, false))
             Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 270kB
             ->  Subquery Scan on subq  (cost=9.93..56590.96 rows=20900 width=236230) (actual time=160.784..140199.364 rows=3705 loops=1)
                   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on atlas_sezioni2 a  (cost=9.93..51052.46 rows=20900 width=236211) (actual time=2.384..308.517 rows=3705 loops=1)
                         Recheck Cond: (ace = 1)
                         Filter: ((pro_com = 15146::numeric) AND ((code)::text = ANY ('{11100,11210,11220,11230,11240,11300,12100,14200}'::text[])))
                         Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                         Heap Blocks: exact=42
                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on atlas_sezioni2_ace_idx  (cost=0.00..9.88 rows=251 width=0) (actual time=0.150..0.150 rows=251 loops=1)
                               Index Cond: (ace = 1)
                         SubPlan 1
                           ->  Limit  (cost=240.70..240.74 rows=15 width=236190) (actual time=0.640..0.646 rows=15 loops=247)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=240.70..240.87 rows=69 width=236190) (actual time=0.637..0.640 rows=15 loops=247)
                                       Sort Key: ((a.geom <-> v.geom))
                                       Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on atlas_sezioni2 v  (cost=4.56..239.01 rows=69 width=236190) (actual time=0.045..0.527 rows=73 loops=247)
                                             Recheck Cond: ((code)::text = '12230'::text)
                                             Filter: (((a.code)::text <> (code)::text) AND (a.pro_com = pro_com))
                                             Heap Blocks: exact=6916
                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on atlas_sezioni2_code_idx  (cost=0.00..4.55 rows=73 width=0) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=73 loops=247)
                                                   Index Cond: ((code)::text = '12230'::text)
 Planning time: 1.117 ms
 Execution time: 140208.187 ms
```

So it does perform better only in the explain :). Real performance doesn't change.